# Delete question with OWN answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, self-answer, vote-to-delete, answered-questions

I can't delete my own question if it has answers. Should the same limit be applied where my own answer is the same? If so, then why?

Scenario: Let's say that I wanted to prove how cool I am and show the world my devastating knowledge. So, I wrote a question and an answer in the same click. Soon, I realize that I'm actually a moron and made a big mistake. So big, that the question (and answer) are not salvageable. And the only solution is to delete both.

I think, in this certain situation, I should be able to delete both question and answer.

Comment: I don't think that it really should be implemented - the prevention of deleting a question with a good answer still applies even if this answer is yours. So if you really want to delete your self-answered question, delete the answer first.

Comment: What about situation (I'm talking about here), where **both** answer and questions are wrong (or contain mistakes, that I don't know how to fix) and answer was upvoted only by some maniac? :>

Comment: We can shorten it lil bit: 1. Delete answer 2. ?????? 3. PROFIT!!!!! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have the only answer on an own question (or there are no (other) positive voted answers), you can delete it following these steps:

- Remove 'accepted' state from your answer;
- Remove answer;
- Remove question.

If you don't have the only answer, and there are answers with a positive score: yes, you shouldn't be able to delete it. **Why would you?** Some people in the community found it useful, so let's keep it! That you answered it too, doesn't mean it shouldn't follow the rules like all other questions.

---

As a side note on the comments: I do agree it is useful to be able to press the delete button on your question when the #1 rules apply. There shouldn't be the need to follow the steps described. It is just the way it goes now.

Comment: I totally agree with you about second scenario (that question shouldn't be deleted, if there are other answers than mine). I was specifically asking about deleting question, when my answer is the only one. But, I didn't knew, that flow of delete-answer + delete+question works like charm. Thx!

Comment: This is still a work-around, isn't it? Why not do #1 and #2 automagically when #3 is attempted?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yeah, true. That might be a good feature request. That OP didn't know this fixes his issue for now. I do support your suggestion though.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Updated my post to reflect my opinion on your comment.

Comment: Agree with all of you, but I was hit so many times here, by some caffeinated rhinos, when trying to open some feature request, that I'm not going to risk this any more! :>

Comment: @trejder: You would have my vote :)

Comment: You have 10x more rep here. It would be my _pleasure_ to vote _your_ feature request! :>

Comment: @PatrickHofman Here you go. Bumped up, but it turned out, that others disagree with us, so it is now all going down! :(

Comment: @trejder: Never mind...